# Is Windows IExpress Still exposes Vulnerability?

Tags: iexpress

I am trying to use I Express and I came across an article stating that it has some vulnerability.

Here is the link: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IExpress.

This is the message from the link:

> **Security**
>
> The self-extracting packages created with IExpress have (inherent) vulnerabilities which allow arbitrary code execution because of the way they handle their installation command and their command line processing.[4][5] Additionally, because of the way Windows User Account Control handles installers, these vulnerabilities allow a privilege escalation.[6][7]

Answer (score 0):

Because Hackers can make a inf. file and if you cilck it, the hacker have full control over your computer. And move one good file to a folder u cant find and make a new one, rename it (Microsoft Edge,File Explorer,etc).